# The banner ad announcing the Developer Survey results

Tags: bug

Regarding the huge banner ad for the developer survey results:

1. The ad's Dismiss button is hard to discover.  (The "Dismiss" is off the right side of the screen at reasonable window sizes, it's extremely low contrast, it's a very thin font weight, and it has no clickability affordance.)
2. The ad won't stay dismissed for more than a couple navigations, even for a logged-in user.  (Follow a link to another Stack Exchange site, then hit the browser Back button: the banner returns.)

I assume the campaign will be over soon, but can we ensure future ones behave in a friendlier way?

Comment: I 'clicked-though' and scrolled all the way to the bottom of the survey results but didn't even get a badge.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen that button at all, I should really thank you. After you have read the results, the banner becomes annoying very quickly.

Comment: Cannot confirm the second point.

Comment: `Follow a link to another Stack Exchange site, then hit the browser Back button: the banner returns.` i.e. refresh the page because cache.

Comment: why dont you install ublock origin and block ad specifically , just suggesting

Comment: @SurajJain Because that's a stop-gap measure to a correctable problem.

Comment: This wasn't a problem for me. I found the "Dismiss" button rather quickly, and never had issues with the banner reappearing (though I never use the back button).

Comment: Regarding the 2nd point: It happens because of browser cache. Just do refresh. The dismiss flag will be stored in your browser cache. If you clear your browser cache after **dismiss**, the banner will appear again.

Comment: Good suggestion, but is it really necessary? I mean, this ad is not intrusive and stuff. (Definitively not like those torrent's pages lmao) IMO, its a friendly ad, very well designed and anyway... I'm ok with that.

Comment: "off the right side of the screen at reasonable window sizes" -- SO's stance seems to be that the number of people seeing horizontal scrolling on the site are too few to matter. At least the top bar scales down now.

Comment: @Frank:  I'm well acquainted with SO designers' disdain for those of us who like to run our browsers on one half of our 1920×1200 monitors (or even to run it full screen with said monitor in portrait mode). :-P

Comment: @SankarRaj:  I'd expect preferences for a logged in user to be associated with the user's account and not a volatile bit of data stashed in the browser's cache.  When I hit the Back button, I see new questions, not just cached ones, so why would the ad state be any different?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy because a script polls for new questions, but the banner is just loaded once? Compare the HNQ sidebar - going back doesn't refresh the list of hot questions.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Not sure I'd be particularly happy if the SO devs spent time coding up somewhere to store the fact that you'd already seen that banner and adding additional functionality to the front page just so you don't have to press F5 once. Whether having the banner there in the first place was such a good idea or not... well that's a very different question.

Comment: Caches get cleared all the time, and I'm not convinced it's the only cause.  The Back button is just the most reliable way to repro.  I'm "dismissing" this ad three to four times a day.  Stop the harassment.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm sitting here amazed that I never saw the banner ad at all. To be sure, it was sitting there at the top of my screen when I looked up, but I'm so mentally conditioned to ignore banner advertisements that having a huge "attention-grabbing" banner at the top of the page actually made my eyes gloss over it completely. It wasn't until I saw this question on the side bar that I noticed anything out of the ordinary. Banners like that seem like a bad idea all round. It annoys half the users and is completely ineffective on the other half.

Comment: @jmbpiano:  100% agreed.  I never actually read the banner.  I just got annoyed that it was eating so much vertical real estate.  I discovered the Dismiss option when I scrolled to the right to hit the Ask Question button.  I've been here eight years, and the first I heard about an annual Developer Survey was a SO blog post a week or so ago.  Many of us are completely blind to banner ads.