# "How are we doing?" persists even after completing the survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-experience, survey, short-survey

It has been stated at ["How are we doing!?" is haunting me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390298/how-are-we-doing-is-haunting-me) that the banner does not go away after dismissing it.

However it does not even go away after completing the survey.

It seems that a similar issue existed 2 years ago: [The banner ad announcing the Developer Survey results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346321/the-banner-ad-announcing-the-developer-survey-results)

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Firefox

Answer (score 6):

This is fixed.

I posted a reply to [How are we doing? Take our short survey. How are we doing? Take our short survey. How are we doing? Take our short survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395901/how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey-how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey/402000#402000) covering the dismiss, but I wanted to call out an earlier change that was made to handle your specific experience.

Kristina's deep dive into the survey code identified that if a user were to open the survey without triggering the dismissal JavaScript, we wouldn't place the user in the "clicked" state, one of the states where users are no longer presented with the banner.  Right clicking the link was one example where a user could open the survey but not dismiss the banner.

To make things more robust, we added backend code to advance users to the clicked state when redirecting to the survey, so the banner would stop appearing even if the frontend code failed to run.