# The Latest "How are we doing?" Survey Banner STILL Fails To Go Away

Tags: bug, status-deferred, survey

The latest "How are we doing?" survey banner won't go away.

Looks like this has happened before:

- [*"How are we doing?" is haunting me*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390298/how-are-we-doing-is-haunting-me)
- [*"How are we doing?" persists even after completing survey*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391364/how-are-we-doing-persists-even-after-completing-the-survey)

Could this please get fixed properly? So that clicking the [x] makes it go away and *stay* gone? Thanks in advance.

---

**Update Feb 1st:** It's not nagging me anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock

Comment: So the answer is "You're not doing great"?

Comment: I finally gave in and "*took*" the survey - and five minutes later the banner is back. lol

Comment: I took the survey.  I'm still being nagged.

Comment: This is currently under investigation. This one's been difficult for us to pin down the cause, and it's in our backlog to address.

Comment: Well, pls do fix it. I had to remove it with a user script.