# How are we doing? Take our short survey. How are we doing? Take our short survey. How are we doing? Take our short survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, user-experience, survey

This is a dupe question.  It's been asked at least three times before:

- ["How are we doing!?" is haunting me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390298/how-are-we-doing-is-haunting-me)
- ["How are we doing?" persists even after completing the survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391364/how-are-we-doing-persists-even-after-completing-the-survey)
- [The Latest "How are we doing?" Survey Banner STILL Fails To Go Away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393431/the-latest-how-are-we-doing-survey-banner-still-fails-to-go-away)

The problem is, none of those questions have been answered - unless you count "*[Huh, that is hella weird](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390360/1767412)*" as an answer. Here we are at least 5 months later with the same annoying problem. It's happening to me now on three different machines — I don't think this should be difficult to reproduce but if staff has any questions I'd be happy to provide answers.

**Will someone please fix this?**

[image]

Comment: Can't read it - continuous page refreshes on my browser:(

Comment: I've answered the damn questions, and it still keeps prompting me to "Take our short survey". Clicking the link of course leads to an error message because I've already taken the survey. Damn annoying.

Comment: I've noticed it's gone on the home page but for all other pages it won't go away. If you hit the top-left hamburger menu, there's also another survey popup that's just as persistent (again, not on the home page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How are we doing!?" is haunting me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390298/how-are-we-doing-is-haunting-me)

Comment: @RobertColumbia - yes, as stated in my question, this is a duplicate or several questions.  As none of them have been answered, I'm hoping it can get answered here.

Comment: [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390360/1767412) does not answer my question nor does it solve this bug.  In fact, it doesn't really seem to answer the question on the other post, of which this has been closed as a dupe.  While I appreciate the bit of info offered there, *it does not answer or solve this ongoing issue*.  If anyone agrees, please re-open my question here.

Comment: Please make it stop! This is sooooo annoying

Comment: if this comment reaches to 10 votes I will write a chrome extension to workaround this

Comment: "How are we doing? Take our short survey" - meh...

Comment: I'm also getting this behavior with the added bonus that the banner returns after few times I visit. If this is not resolved or at least addressed, it will be added as an adblocker rule.

Comment: "How are we doing? Take our short survey" - imho the way the banner issue and the related questions are handled provide a first answer ...

Comment: You can kill it with an Ad Blocker,  then again you can vote with your feet.

Comment: It's worth pointing out as a new survey has been added, this is still a thing. - Ref ["Take our short survey" appears every time I open SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397918) - ([Comment by Cody](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/772939) in relation to this request).

Comment: I just realised this post is from March. I hate everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fixed.

While working in a related area, I identified the likely causes of the problem by almost accidentally making happen more frequently and in a more predictable way.

As it turns out, we have two calls to action for the survey<sup>[1]</sup>, one in the banner and one that lives as a popover on the bottom of the page (technically, and importantly for our case, in the left nav).

The page when constructed looks something like this:

```html
<div class="js-survey-thing" data-cookie-info="...">BANNER</div>
...
<div class="left-nav">
    <div class="js-survey-thing">POPOVER</div>
</div>
```

The code for wiring the UI looked like this:

```javascript
var $notice = $('.js-survey-thing');
var cookieInfo = $notice.data('cookieInfo');
$notice.each(configureNotice);
function configureNotice() {
    ...
}
```

I ran into some trouble when refactoring the code to look closer to this:

```javascript
$('.js-survey-thing').each(configureNotice);
function configureNotice() {
    var $notice = $(this);
    var cookieInfo = $notice.data('cookieInfo');
    ...
}
```

Since the popover CTA didn't have `data-cookie-info`, the code for configuring the sidebar failed to retrieve the cookie information and wrote the dismissed state to an unnamed cookie.

A similar thing would happen and trigger this bug's behavior if the DOM looked like this when the configuration JavaScript ran:

```html
<div class="left-nav">
    <div class="js-survey-thing">POPOVER</div>
</div>
...
<div class="js-survey-thing" data-cookie-info="...">BANNER</div>
```

In this case `$('.js-survey-thing').data('cookieInfo');` returns null (or undefined?) because `data` returns the contents of the data attribute from the first element it encounters.

So, do we ever enter a state where the DOM looks like this when the JavaScript runs, and do we do it in a limited set of circumstances that would make it unlikely for developers to repro, causing months of confusion and frustration for the entire public platform team?

**Yes, we do!**

If you look at your screen recording, you see that you don't have a popover in the lower left corner of the screen *and* you don't have a left navigation of any kind.  Instead you have a hamburger menu in the top corner of your screen which brings up the left navigation in a dialog.  This dialog lives inside the topbar element above the survey banner.  The code that moves the element there fires before we call the survey code, so dismissing the banner never writes to the right place.

This hamburger menu behavior is configured by a user preference.  Of course, very few users have this setting turned on and no one had it turned on in their local environments, so we would get infrequent but persistent bug reports that we were never able to reproduce.  The moral here?  Every conditional increases complexity?  Complex systems fail in complex ways?  Never rule out the frontend?

My fix was to make sure both survey CTAs had the required data attributes and continue with my refactoring of the UI code.  There's obvious performance costs here, partially offset by gzip compression, but it improves the resilience to this kind of issue.

Hopefully this was the true root cause and we don't see it reported again next month.

<sup>[1]  It seems odd that we have two on the page at the same time, but it turns out to be surprisingly effective at driving completion with different user types.</sup>

Comment: great news.  thanks for the detailed, technical breakdown of the factors at play here!

Comment: You're putting groundhogs out of business https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtAZ.png :)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for your report (and thanks to everyone else who's reported this issue, too)! This is a "fun" one. The short version is that every single developer on the public platform team has tried to reliably reproduce this bug, and we... might have resolved it? At least, we narrowed the problem down to a couple of potential issues: right-click handling, and account history records.

Regarding right clicks, we realized that we were only setting the correct cookie for "survey link clicked" on left click, so if a user opened the survey in a new tab with a right click, they'd be able to access the survey, but the banner would still show up. That unfortunately doesn't account for the survey showing up even after it's dismissed.

The account history issue is a lot more hand-wavy in how it might explain this bug. Basically, we're looking at a couple of different account statuses in a couple of different places when we check to see if the survey should show up for a particular person. Some users seem to be able to get themselves into a state where they're able to log a "viewed survey banner" action even after they've logged a "completed survey" action, which would indicate that one of our checks, somewhere, is sometimes checking the wrong thing, and then because the most recent action, a view, is not disqualifying, it continues to show. We haven't found the precise issue, but we are refactoring the code to make it much simpler and make the checks more robust.

We know this isn't the most satisfying answer, but we figured we should err on the side of giving you an unsatisfying update instead of maintaining radio silence. If you're still experiencing this bug, please let us know. The bug reports we've received about this have been immensely helpful in tracking down this issue, and the more we have, the more likely we are to be able to find the common thread causing it. I'm removing the 'status-review' tag for now, but you can definitely re-add it if you experience this bug again. Thanks!

Comment: Could this also explain why some users are never presented the survey?

Comment: I think that's possible, but there are other checks we perform to see if a user should get the survey, too. For example, some users have opted out of surveys, some are in Teams (so we give them different surveys), etc. And we also sample a small fraction of users so it might take a while before a user gets a survey, regardless.

Comment: Hi - Both the screenshot gif I provided and the one in the subsequent edit show a user only clicking the dismiss **`×`** on the banner's right side - not viewing the survey or right clicking anywhere. While it may be possible that the avenues you mentioned are related, I don't see how either one directly addresses this particular question since in this case the banner *is never viewed* - only dismissed. I'd think clicking the dismissal button would set a cookie to prevent the banner from showing up again and we shouldn't need to view the survey for that to happen.

Comment: So what you're saying is that this is now just another _"Huh, that is hella weird"_ answer 

Comment: @billynoah The banner appearing on your screen means that it's viewed, the survey just hasn't been clicked. You're correct about what the dismiss button does, I just didn't include all of the nitty gritty details in my writeup. I do also think it's possible that there is more than one culprit, perhaps even unrelated to each other, as the behavior is so difficult to repro and it seems to occur under different circumstances.

Comment: @phil We haven't closed the issue internally - we have some fixes in the works, as I mentioned in my response above, and are keeping an eye on new reports in the hopes that, if it's still happening, we can use those additional reports to better isolate the issue.

Comment: @kristinalustig - thanks for elaborating.  I didn't get that from your answer but it's helpful

Comment: @kristinalustig would you handle middle click? Or would generalize to any click?

Comment: This is not fixed. The banner has just appeared for me and keeps coming back on every page except the the home page - despite being dismissed with the cross button.

Comment: Hi @Turnip - just so you know, I'm not ignoring this! Finally have another chance to dig in again to see if this additional report will give us the repro we need to fix this bug. Are you able to walk me through the steps? More specifically, did you take the survey or click on the link at any point, or did you just dismiss the banner? Also - do you happen to have any notable browser settings active, like having all cookies disabled? Any other info like that? Thank you so much.