# "Take our short survey" appears every time I open SO

Tags: bug, survey-2020

Every time open Stackoverflow it asks me to take the survey.

But I've completed it yesterday.

---

[image]

---

I've tried to dismiss it manually but after page refresh it appears again.

Of course, if I click on button I am getting the following message:

---

[image]

---

**Expected result:** After submitting the survey I should not be asked to take it again.

Comment: Please note that by closing this as a duplicate, I do not aim to dismiss your concerns. I tagged that question [[meta-tag:status-review]] almost a month ago, which should have escalated it to be reviewed directly by staff. Unfortunately, we still haven't heard anything from them. There is nothing more that moderators or community members can do here.

Comment: @CodyGray I was trying to find already existing question. But seems that this issue is pretty old. So thank you for that.

Comment: i mean, at least you get the survey

Comment: @CodyGray the other question isn't getting much attention and this is still an issue. I'm sick of seeing the blue banner at the top of the screen every time I refresh or click a link.